# HTML/Javascript Confusion

Tags: javascript, html

I have an extremely basic html document written as the following:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>A Basic Javascript Game</title>
</head>
<body>
<script language="JavaScript" src="mygame.js">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've created an according Javascript file, have made sure that it's syntax is alright. The first line of the mygame.js file is:

```
var persontotalkto = prompt("You wake up one Saturday morning. The Holidays just started, and you can't wait to tell your family where you've decided for all of us to go on vacation! Who do you talk to: WIFE, SON, or DAUGHTER?").toUpperCase();
```

But when I open the html file, I'm not getting any prompt whatsoever. I have javascript enabled, so what is the problem?

Comment: `<script language="Javascript">` is deprecated, you should use `type="text/javascript"` instead. Anyway, check if the file `mygame.js` is inside the folder of your HTML page.

Comment: If you look in your console, do you see any errors?

Comment: your line works for me. use the javascript console to see if it's complaining about anything (Safari => Develop => Show Error Console)

Comment: remove `toUppercase()`

Comment: Make sure the path to the js file is correct - it will fail silently if the path is incorrect.

Comment: Are you sure that `src` of `js` file is correct path? Add an `alert("yes")` to check it.

Comment: Have you tried it by replacing the reference of the file by the code itself?
replace
<script language="JavaScript" src="mygame.js">
by
<script language="JavaScript">prompt("You wake up one Saturday morning. The Holidays just started, and you can't wait to tell your family where you've decided for all of us to go on vacation! Who do you talk to: WIFE, SON, or DAUGHTER?").toUpperCase();
</script>

Comment: @LightStyle, I've swapped out the code for the one you have, thanks for the correction! As far as having the javascript file inside the folder of my html page, how do i do that? In the past, i always saved both on desktop just to try it out, but its not working.

Comment: @JeroenIngelbrecht, I have tried this. It does not seem to work.

Comment: have you disabled javascript by any chance in your browser settings?

Comment: @JeroenIngelbrecht I'm using Chrome, and I've checked the settings to make sure that Javascript has been enabled. It looks like it's been this way, so I don't think that was the problem.

Comment: try this jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/7hYPk/

Answer (score 0):

Change the script tag to either the HTML4 version:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="mygame.js"></script>
```

Or the HTML5

```
<script src="mygame.js"></script>
```

(Either will work on any browser released this millennium.)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="mygame.js">
</script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="mygame.js">
</script>
```

Comment: how is this different from fakerainbirds answer??